# Splitting a dictionary into an array of keys and array of value

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I have the following dictionary.

```
assistDict: [String: Int] = ["Modric": 5, "Vinicius": 4, "Kroos ": 2, "Mendy ": 4, "CR7": 6, "Casemiro ": 2, "Carvajal ": 1, "Rodrygo": 11, "KB9": 9, "kaka": 16.
```

My goal is to split assistDict into two arrays: an arrays of keys and arrays of value sharing the same index.
I tried this:

```
let playerName = assistDict.map{$0.key}
let playerAssistValue = assistDict.map{$0.value}
```

The output is :

```
  ["KB9", "Casemiro ", "Kroos ", "Rodrygo", "Carvajal ", "Mendy ", "Vinicius", "Modric", "CR7", "kaka"]

  [5, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2, 1, 11, 9, 16]
```

But it does not split the keys in order as in the dictionary. How could I achieve that.
Output should be :

```
["Modric", "Vinicius ", "Kroos ", "Mendy", "CR7 ", "Casemiro ", "Carvajal", "Rodrygo", "KB9", "kaka"]
[5, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2, 1, 11, 9, 16]
```

Comment: "But it does not split the keys in order as in the dictionary" The dictionary _has no order_. No. Order. If you need something like a literal dictionary that does have an order, use a KeyValuePairs.

Comment: oh so I should change the type assistDict to another collection >

Comment: Yes, if you wanted an ordered array of key value pairs you should have started with an array of key value pairs. A dictionary is not that. It is a device for _rapid lookup_ by key. The keys in the dictionary itself have no order.